# Analytical solution to the integral of ∫ x'dx?

Tags: integration, closed-form, symbolic-computation

I want to find the closed form of the integral

$$\int \dot{x} dx \tag{1}$$

where $\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt}$. I think there should be an analytical solution. I know

$$\int \dot{x} dx = \int \dot{x}^2 dt  \tag{2}$$

and maybe using the equation $\dot{x}^2 = (x + \dot{x})^2 - x^2 - 2x\dot{x}$, but then I don't know how to go further. I would appreciate if you could help me with this. I have also asked this question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/ar82w6/analytical_solution_to_the_integral_xdx/) on Reddit.

**P.S.**

I'm not entirely sure but maybe this is the solution:

If we consider that $\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt}$ then

$$\int \dot{x} dx = \frac{ d}{dt} \left(\int x dx \right) \tag{3}$$

which yields:

$$\int \dot{x} dx = x \dot{x} \tag{4}$$

Comment: In general you cannot go further than $\int f'(t)^2\mathop{dt}$, I don't think it has a general expression in term of $f(t)$ other than that. If $f$ verify an ODE where you can express $f''$ in term of $f,f'$ (e.g. trig functions) then you can integrate by parts, but else you are stuck.

Comment: (3) is just wrong. try it with examples functions, you'll see quickly. (2) is right. Look at (4) it behaves like $\int \dot x\mathop{dx}=\dot x\int\mathop{dx}=\dot x x$ as if $\dot x$ was a constant. This can't be right...

Comment: @Foad Given the mistakes you made you should make clear what is a function of what, ie. $x(t)$ is a function of $t$, $y = x(t) \implies t = x^{-1}(y)$ and $ \int_a^z \dot{x} dx \overset{def} =C+ \int_a^z x'(x^{-1}(y)) dy$, then let the change of variable $y = x(t),dy = x'(t)dt$

Comment: @reuns it is actually part of the differential equation below:  $$m \ddot{x} + \beta \dot{x} + k x + M sgn\left(\dot{x}\right) - F = 0$$ where m, $\beta$, k,  M and F are constants

Comment: @Foad, No differentiable function can solve that equation unless $M = 0$. Rewriting it as $M\text{sgn}(\dot x) = F - \ddot x - \beta\dot x + kx$, the discontinuous LHS must be equal to the continuous RHS. The best you can do is solve for $m \ddot{x} + \beta \dot{x} + k x + M - F = 0$, take only the region where $\dot x > 0$, then solve $m \ddot{x} + \beta \dot{x} + k x - M - F = 0$ for the other region. The resulting $x$ will be discontinuous at those points.